# How to stop broken images showing

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a table with some images that I want to start out with no images in them.I have set the src="".But when viewed in a browser it shows broken image pics.

```
<tr>
<td><img src=""> </td>
<td><img src=""> </td>
<td><img src=""></td>
</tr>
```

How can I prevent the browser from showing the broken image pics or X or whatever until I put some data
into the src attribute.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**Simply don't put those `img` elements there.** They have no semantic value. Also, you should read this article: [Empty image src can destroy your site on NCZOnline](http://www.nczonline.net/blog/2009/11/30/empty-image-src-can-destroy-your-site/)

I guess you're changing the image source with Javascript anyways. You should simply add an `img` in the cell if there is not one yet (see the example in the [MDC appendChild() page](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DOM/Node.appendChild)).

*(Another, uglier solution is to hide the images by default (`style="display: none;"`), and only display them with Javascript if they get an `src`. But you should do the first one.)*

Answer (score 33):

Add this inline event handler,

```
<img src="broken.png" onerror="this.style.display='none'" />
```

Comment: Adding alt="" as a fallback might be a good idea just in case users don't have JS enabled.

Answer (score 25):

Very simple answer is add alt attribute with empty value

```
<img src="" alt="" width="50" height="50"/>
```

width & height are optional

Comment: Simple, no-CSS, no-Javascript, cross-browser working workaround. Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

Don't use images that point to nothing.

You *could* style them to have no visibility (will not work if you have *anything* in the `src` attribute, even if it is a bad URL):

```
img[src=''] 
{
  display: none;
}
```

But as I already said, if you don't have an image do display, don't put the tag on the page.

Comment: The best answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

That's not really an answer to your question, but for completeness' sake:
One can remove the image on a loading error (e.g. with an inline script).

```
<img src="broken.png" onerror="this.parentNode.removeChild(this)">
```

Answer (score 3):

Great solution that really helped me

```
img {  
  font-family: 'Helvetica';
  font-weight: 300;
  line-height: 2;  
  text-align: center;

  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  display: block;
  position: relative;
}

img:after {  
  content: attr(alt);
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 2;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #fff;
}
```

Idea from https://bitsofco.de/styling-broken-images/

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<img src="http://someurl.com" width='0' height='0'>
```

Why would you want to do that? I'm using an invisible image to track users -- it hits that url, which is not actually an image and doesn't return one, and logs the user making the request. I'm doing this in environments where I don't have client-side scripting (html email and Google Sites), and this is the easiest way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Don't put them there. Just insert them later with `$('someelement').append("image");`

Answer (score 0):

The `src` attribute is required to point to an image; if you have no image, don't use the `img` element.

You could use any other element and set the `background-image` property if required.

Answer (score 0):

I’d suggest using CSS to hide the image tags initially:

```
<img src="" style="visibility: hidden;">
```

Then amend that from your JavaScript when you add the image URL:

```
yourImgObject.src = 'IMAGEURL';
yourImgObject.style.visibility = 'visible'
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using [Semantic UI React](https://react.semantic-ui.com/) you can pass the `img` element to `onError` through the event's `target` property:

```html
<Image src={imageObject.Url} onError={i => i.target.src=''} />
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to get rid of broken image icon & don't want to hide the image and want to keep the resolution of it as is; Use a transparent **base-64 image**, to replace it.

*Jquery:*

```
$("img").on("error", function() {
    $(this).attr('src' ,'data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAEAAAABCAQAAAC1HAwCAAAAC0lEQVR42mNkYAAAAAYAAjCB0C8AAAAASUVORK5CYII=');
});
```

**Pros:**

- No need to hide the image
- No need to change Alt text of the image
- base-64 image don't have specific height-width
- works with jquery zoom (jquery.zoom.js), if the zoomed image is broken

Answer (score 0):

I would just build on what others have provided by adding a placeholder or fallback image when the primary source is invalid. That way, you're guaranteed to return SOMETHING useful to the user. This is especially helpful when the source is service-driven or RESTful.

Source: [missing-images-on-website](https://themeisle.com/blog/missing-images-on-website/)

```
<img
    src="<%- data.primaryImage.url %>"
    alt="image description"
    onerror="this.onerror=null; this.src='unavailable.png';"
/>
```