# How do i remove broken image box?

Tags: html, css, html-table

I am trying to build an email template in which i have to show some images to different mail client (eg.. outlook, thunderbird...). Now problem is when these clients does not allow to show image at that time broken image box is displaying which i don't want to display.

I had also refer

Refered link [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BgR34.jpg): [How to remove borders around broken images in webkit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13151340/how-to-remove-borders-around-broken-images-in-webkit)

Refered link [2]: [input type="image" shows unwanted border in Chrome and broken link in IE7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4108983/input-type-image-shows-unwanted-border-in-chrome-and-broken-link-in-ie7)

Refered link [3]: [How to stop broken images showing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6622353/how-to-stop-broken-images-showing)

but not able to find any proper output. 
Note : I can not use div tag. I must have to use table tags.

CODE What I am using :

```
<table style="background:#fff; width:600px; margin:auto auto;">
<tr>
    <td>
    <a href="http://www.sampleurl.com">
    <img src="http://sampleimageurl.com/sampleimage.png" height="55" width="198" />
    </a>
    </td>
    <td style="text-align:right;"><a href="http://www.sampleurl.com" target="_blank">
        <span style="font-family:Myriad Pro; color:#0d5497; font-size:20px;">www.sampleurl.com</span>
    </td>
</tr>

<!--<tr>
    <td colspan="2" style="height:1px; background: #0d5497;"></td>

</tr>-->
```

OUTPUT what i get.
[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

use `alt` here for fallback

[**demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/v8DLe/)

html

```
<img src="abc" alt="image" />
```

**css**

```
img {
    width:200px;
    height:200px;
}
```

**Alternatively**, if you dont want to show any `alt text`, just give a blank space.

[**demo here**](http://jsfiddle.net/v8DLe/1/)

**HTML**

```
<img src="abc" alt=" " />
```

Comment: i had try this. but the thing is i am not allow to display alt text. either i have to show image or nothing. not even broken image icon and box

Comment: Why are you not allowed to show alt text or use a div in your email?

Answer (score 6):

I know I'm late to the party but I didn't see a simple solution that used native javascript. Here is the solution I came up with

```
<img src="https://test.com/broken-image.gif" onerror="arguments[0].currentTarget.style.display='none'">
```

onerror calls a function, passing an error event as an argument. Because the argument is not actually defined as 'error' we need to get it from the arguments array that all functions have. Once we have the error we can get the currentTarget, our img tag, and sent the display to none.

Answer (score 3):

I think you can use on error event on img.

[here is a simple solution](http://jsfiddle.net/Je7yF/)

Please pay attention that this script uses onDomReady event. In this case you should write:

```
<script type="text/javascript">//<![CDATA[ 
    $(function(){
            $('img').on('error', function () {
            $(this).remove();
        })
     });//]]>  
</script>
```

**UPDATE**

Why do you load images ? You can attach this image to email and show it via [CID](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4312687/how-to-embed-images-in-email)

Comment: jQuery dependant in email template?

Comment: ah, this is for email.. than forget this answer :)

Comment: Nice idea though, surely standard js might work - but js execution in some clients maybe an issue

Comment: @Anand Mehta, 
Why do you load images ? You can attach this image to email and show it via CID

Comment: Generally Javascript in emails is stripped y the client for security reasons

Answer (score 1):

You could any other element instead of and `IMG` and set the `background-image` using CSS. If that image is not found, you will not get the strange looking box.

```
<span style="background-image:url('http://sampleimageurl.com/sampleimage.png'); display:inline-block; width:198px; height:55px">
     element with background
</span>
```

Comment: I already mention that i am not able to use div tag. i had also try that to. but i am restrict to use of div tag

Comment: Removed the div (Although I do not understand why you cannot use it).  You can basically use ANY element and use CSS to style it properly.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like a tough call not being allowed to use ALT text

If whoever is making this decision is convinced by a bit of styling you can do that e.g.

```
<img src="logo.jpg" width="400" height=”149″ alt="Company Name" style="font-family: Georgia; color: #697c52; font-style: italic; font-size: 30px; background:#ccffcc">
```

see http://jsbin.com/IcIVubU/1/

Answer (score 1):

use this code block in your mail content to keep unrendered image as hidden.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<img id="imgctrl" src="imgs/sandeep11.png" onerror="$('#' + this.id).hide();" alt="Alternate Text" />
```

concept is.. use any CDN jquery reference then only jquery code will work. and I guess your src image path also should be some live url. if not then, it should be in attachment.

> Please Click on "Show Remote content" to get remote urls into
>   thunderbird. this is security constraint of thunderbird. that's why
>   your images are not being loaded.

Answer (score 1):

I know it is an old question but I found I had this problem too today (08 January 2020) and found a way to get around it.
I tested with the latest versions of **Firefox** and **Chrome**, I still could not find a solution for **Safari**.

**Firefox**:
For firefox you must add `alt=" "` note the space

**Chrome**:
For Chrome it must be `alt=""` note the empty space

The problem is that when I add the space the icon shows up on Chrome and disappears on Firefox, and vice versa when I remove it.

I added just a space because I did not want any text showing up on the image.

I did not have to add any of the following lines for it to work (I saw many solutions proposing some or all of them), but I left them in just in case

```
border: none;
outline: none;
border-image: none;
```

From there I guess it would be detecting a the browser in JavaScript and changing the alt attribut to " " or "".

Answer (score 0):

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {
    document.querySelectorAll('img').forEach(function(img){
        img.onerror =function(){this.parentNode.removeChild(this);
    })});
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, it is better to explain how to solve the problem and provide the code as an example or reference. Code-only answers can be confusing and lack context.

Answer (score -1):

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/v8DLe/4/)**

you can remove `img` by javascript:

```
arr = document.getElementsByTagName("img");
for(i=0; i<arr.length; i++){
    if(arr[i].src=="")
        arr[i].parentElement.removeChild(arr[i]);
}
```

Comment: What is this ? o_O You just remove all images.


`if(arr[i].src="") `


this is always true :)

anyway images are always with src, url is broken for some images

Comment: Don't use javascript in email. That is just evil.

Comment: No, it's just a simple code that remove image with empty *src* attribute, see DEMO again.

Comment: @RobAu so use this for create template before send.