# Drive showing broken image icon for unknown file type

Tags: google-drive-api

Drive is showing a broken image link for unknown file type (see image).

Is this a bug? Do we need (as a vendor) to provide the image in the manifest?

[Broken link?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yXWSz.png)

Comment: For unknown reason now the link return the correct image:

https://drive-thirdparty.googleusercontent.com/32/type/application/vnd.balsamiq.3.bmpr

Comment: The mystery continue now the link sometimes return a 200 code with 0 payload

https://drive-thirdparty.googleusercontent.com/32/type/application/vnd.balsamiq.3.bmpr

Comment: I guess that you'll need to provide the image in the manifest. As stated in this [blog](http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/how-to-fix-a-broken-image), you’ll need to specify where that image is located and on which website. Also, sometimes when you’re uploading your website to a server, the permissions can accidentally change for some reason. If you navigate to your web page and a file has the wrong permissions, it could cause a broken image. You can also check this related [SO post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6622353/how-to-stop-broken-images-showing).