# How to show only empty squares if user does not upload any image instead of showing null icon

Tags: html, css

Here if user upload a image it will show the uploaded image. But in other case if user forget to upload images or images is not uploaded then instead of showing this icon[image]

I want to show only empty squares. So please let me know if it is possible. or How can we achieve this

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to hide image broken Icon using only CSS/HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22051573/how-to-hide-image-broken-icon-using-only-css-html)

Comment: it is not at all showing any thing. In my case if images is not uploaded only square box has to display

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6622396/14141568 This answer seemed to work for me

Comment: Thanks @ramya Your solutions it seems it is working. But in my case we have given path "src="http://127.0.0.1:5000/media/"

Answer (score 1):

Did you try onerror with the image tag?

```
<img src="media.jpg" onerror="this.onerror=null; this.src='https://toppng.com/uploads/preview/and-blank-effect-transparent-11546868080xgtiz6hxid.png'"/>
```

something like this.

Answer (score 0):

you can make sure the url you are loading from is not null if it is instead of creating an image tag create a div that is styled as a box